# C++ atomic variable compare and increment

Tags: c++, atomic

I would like to know how to make the following function in a whole atomic.

With my code, I believe there can be a situation that two threads both pass the condition, and return 0,1 respectively right?

```
static std::atomic<uintV> shared_v (0);
int compare_increment() {
  if (shared_v >= 10) {
    return -1;
  } 
  return shared_v++;
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Correct. You must use an explicit mutex.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik wow thank you for the quick response. If I include mutex, it would be no longer necessary to make the shared variable atomic right?

Comment: @NateEldredge nice idea, thanks!

Comment: @Baup  correct. If you use a mutex, you don’t need std::atomic

Comment: compare-exchange is what you want. Do an atomic read into a regular variable. Compare it, add 1 to it, then write it back using a compare-exchange with the original value. If some other code changed it while you were comparing and adding to it, it will fail. If comp-exch fails, loop back to read it again and repeat the whole operation until it succeeds.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `compare_exchange_weak` in a loop to achieve this sort of read-modify-write effect without a mutex.

Example (untested):

```
int compare_increment() {
    uintV old = shared_v.load();
    do {
        if (old >= 10)
            return -1;
    } while (!shared_v.compare_exchange_weak(old, old+1));
    return old;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I wrote one for a bit of fun.

```
$ cat compare-exchange-atomic-test.cpp
```

---

```
#include <array>
#include <atomic>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

std::atomic<int> value{0};
std::atomic<int> loops{0};
int comparison_target = 10;

void f() {
  int v;
  do {
    v = value;
    if (v < comparison_target) {
      return;
    }
    ++loops;
  } while (!value.compare_exchange_weak(v, v + 1));
}

void g() {
  int i;
  for (i = 0; i < 1000; ++i) {
    f();
  }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  if (argc > 1) {
    comparison_target = std::stoi(argv[1]);
  }

  std::array<std::thread, 64> threads;
  for (auto &x : threads) {
    x = std::thread(g);
  }

  for (auto &x : threads) {
    x.join();
  }

  std::cout << value << ' ' << comparison_target << ' ' << loops << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

---

```
$ g++ -Wall -W -pedantic -g -O3 -flto -fno-fat-lto-objects -mcpu=native -DNDEBUG -pthread -MMD  -fPIC -fPIE -std=c++17  compare-exchange-atomic-test.cpp -pthread -flto -fno-fat-lto-objects  -o compare-exchange-atomic-test

$ ./compare-exchange-atomic-test 1
0 1 0

$ ./compare-exchange-atomic-test 0
64000 0 455100

$ ./compare-exchange-atomic-test 0
64000 0 550596
```